# MODX Revo считать и сохранить значение из базы

Tags: modx, revo

MODX только начал изучать, не ругайтесь. Нужно увеличить счетчик на 1. Сделал числовое доп. поле countOfShow, читаю данные в чанке так: [[+tv.countOfShow]], пятёрочка видится. Я так понимаю, нужно вызвать сниппет

```
[[!IncCountOfShow? &docid=`[[+id]]`]]
```

Нужно просто увеличить значение на 1 и сохранить.
Так не получается

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['docid'])){
    $user = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVarResource',['contentid'=>$_GET['docid']]);
    $count = $user->get('countOfShow');
    $count++;
    $user->save();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так правильно:

```
<?php
if ($tv=$modx->getObject('modTemplateVarResource', array('tmplvarid' => 16, 'contentid' => $docid))) {
$count = $tv->get('value');
$count++;
$tv->set('value', $count);
$tv->save(); 
}
```

Comment: Можете сократить код, удалив 2 и 3 строки, а 4 заменив на `$tv->set('value', $tv->get('value') + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Вы не задали новое значение перед сохранением: $user->set();
Прочитайте курс по работе с xPDO, многие вопросы отойдут - https://ilyaut.ru/xpdo/